# Rails 3 NoMethodError: undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

All of a sudden I started to get two different errors with one of my Models. I have no idea what I changed, but my code doesn't seem to be the problem.

I entered the rails console. I typed QuestiNon.find(:all) and I got all the records I have entered so far.  But, if I try

```
ruby-1.8.7-p352 :003 > Question.find(55)
NoMethodError: undefined method `eq' for nil:NilClass
from /home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing'
from /home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:299:in `find_one'
from /home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:289:in `find_with_ids'
from /home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:107:in `find'
from /home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/base.rb:444:in `__send__'
from /home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/base.rb:444:in `find'
from (irb):3
```

I have double checked and the id 55 does exist

And if I try the create method I get:

```
ruby-1.8.7-p352 :004 > Question.create("question" => "something")
NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
from /home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing'
from /home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/arel-2.0.10/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:56:in `visit_Arel_Nodes_InsertStatement'
from /home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/arel-2.0.10/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:55:in `map'
from /home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/arel-2.0.10/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:55:in `visit_Arel_Nodes_InsertStatement'
from /home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/arel-2.0.10/lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:15:in `send'
from /home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/arel-2.0.10/lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:15:in `visit'
from /home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/arel-2.0.10/lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:5:in `accept'
from /home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/arel-2.0.10/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:18:in `accept'
from /home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:111:in `with_connection'
from /home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/arel-2.0.10/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:16:in `accept'
```

Googling around some people suggested the problem is due to a primary_key configuration, but I have not set a new primary key. My models primary key should be id.

My question.rb is like this:

> class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
>
> set_table_name "questions"
>
> end

and my table is like this:

```
from (irb):4ruby-1.8.7-p352 :005 > ActiveRecord::Base.connection.columns("questions").map{|c| [c.name, c.type] } 
 => [["id", :integer], ["question_type", :integer], ["question", :string], ["mandatory", :boolean], ["help", :string], ["answers", :string], ["question_number", :integer], ["survey_id", :string], ["created_at", :datetime], ["updated_at", :datetime]]
```

The weird thing is that this is working fine in my server with MYSQL, but locally with SQLITE3 it is not.

How can I fix this? Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: are you using a HABTM relationship?

Comment: No, I am not using HABTM

Comment: I have added my question.rb file and the table's columns

Comment: Swap the order of your question_type and question string in the model. I think you're not mapping it properly. You might need to run rake db:migrate to update your sqlite model

Comment: Any luck with this? What if you try `Question.find_by_id(55)`. Just out of interest, how come you are using `set_table_name` when the conventions are not being broken? Surely no need? Finalyl, what happens if you type `Question.primary_key` at cmd? I know you think you have not changed the primary key, but you never know...

Comment: Question.find_by_id(55) works fine. Question.primary_key returns "id"
About the set_table_name, I had to use it after I ran a migration, somehow it messed up the server side (MySQL) and by setting the table name like that fixed that issue. Any other ideas I should try with my Question's table? thx